# Quicken + Sorcery at the end step

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Quicken allows me to cast a sorcery "any time I could cast an instant", but I don't want my opponents to know I am planning to do that, is the following legal?:

1. The player before me pass the turn
2. I respond casting quicken in the end step
3. No one respondes so Quicken resolve
4. I now cast my sorcery, still in his end step

Is the fourth step valid? Do I get the priority again after Quicken resolves but before my turn starts to cast my sorcery at instant speed?

Comment: What is the question that, if answered, would help *you* determine whether or not step 4 is valid? For example, "Can I cast multiple spells in one step?" or "Can I cast spells in the end step?" are both good questions.